# Is there a method that converts JTS Geometries to Oracle Geometries (SDO) in the hibernate.spatial package?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I am trying to reach break points in eclipse. I have found a method that convers an oracle to a JTS Geometry (convert in SDOGeometryValueExtrator) but I cannot find the opposite. Is there a class that does does the opposite (convert JTS to oracle). I was looking for something like toSDOGeometry but I couldn't find it in the jar.